# RXJS Angular call a method once and store result, return stored data in all subsequent request

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

Fetch data from lookup tables!

If already fetched get data from localStorage or fetch by service and store into localStorage.

If previous request is already in process, other request should wait to complete, so they can get data from localStorage

pseudo code:

```
isInProgress = false;
getLookup(lookupName: string) {
  if(this.isInProgress)
     // Code to wait, no delay or timer, please


  if(localStorage(lookupName)){
     return of(localStorage.get(lookupName));
  } else {
      this.isInProgress = true;
      let url = `..../getLooup?name= {lookupName}`;
      this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(data => {
         // Some other code to process the logic
         let processedData = someProcess(data);
         localStorage.set(lookupName, processedData);
         this.isInProgress = false;
         return of(processedData)
      }, error => {
         this.isInProgress = false;
         // Log error and other code
      })
  }
}
```

I am not very good in RXJS, might be a simple solution!

If it will be called like this:

```
xvyService.getLookup('A').subscribe(.....);
xvyService.getLookup('A').subscribe(.....);
xvyService.getLookup('A').subscribe(.....);
xvyService.getLookup('A').subscribe(.....);
```

Database should not hit more than once.

Comment: Uh, what's the question?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: sorry, might be I was not clear, so added some lines for example

Comment: Might be a good idea to make that at an interceptor level. If you need a condition maybe just pass a header on the request you want like `LOCAL_STORAGE_CACHE`

Answer (score 1):

`shareReplay` can be used to implement a simple cache. It subscribes to the source Observable once on the first subscription and replays values to all later subscriptions. Later subscriptions "wait" automatically if no value can be replayed immediately.

General logic

```js
if value in local storage
  return from local storage
else if cache not initialized
  cache = apiCall.pipe(
    // do things on first call only
    shareReplay(1) // replay last value
    // do things on all calls
  )
endif
return cache
```

**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwbtyc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```js
let cache$: Observable<any>;

getLookup(lookupName: string): Observable<any> {
  const fromStorage = localStorage.getItem("lookupName");
  if (fromStorage) {
    console.log("from local storage");
    return of(JSON.parse(fromStorage));
  } else if (!this.cache$) {
    console.log("initializing cache");
    this.cache$ = this.requestData().pipe(
      map(data => {
        console.log('doing stuff');
        const processedData = { ...data, a: 1 }
        localStorage.setItem("lookupName", JSON.stringify(processedData));
        return processedData
      }),
      shareReplay(1),
      // Move catchError above shareReplay if you want to replay the safe error value instead
      catchError(error => {
        // Log error and other code - return default value on error
        return of(null);
      })
      // Populate local storage on every call and not just the first one
      //tap(data => localStorage.setItem("lookupName", JSON.stringify(data)))
    );
  }
  return this.cache$;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In one place you return Observable - `of(localStorage.get(lookupName))`, in other you return Observable in subscribe - `return of(processedData)`. It doesn't work that because in the first case you work synchronously but in next you work asynchronously.

You can try something like:

```
if (localStorage(lookupName)) {
  return of(localStorage.get(lookupName));
}       

return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
  take(1),
  map((data) => {
    let processedData = someProcess(data);
    localStorage.set(lookupName, processedData);
    return processedData
  }));
```

and

`xvyService.getLookup('A').subscribe((data) => console.log(data));`

HttpClient should cancel request so `this.isInProgress` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: take(1) will take 1 request at a time, but all will queued up to call the data from database, put the log and try

Comment: My code gets or set localStorage data you should in the place where you call this method, check this method should be run again. When we call this method in one time a lot of times, HttpClient should cancel requests, only last should be executed.

Comment: if all the request is coming once, they all will already be passed if(locals....), where is the code to stop the request, or to re-check the localStorage

Comment: I've checked it and I agree with you requests don't cancel but you should decide how many time this method should be executed, You should run one time and wait.

Comment: Why do you want to call this method a lot of times?

Comment: I don't want to call but application will do, different component will call it, and once those component will be used on a page, they all will call the same method at the same time, anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something along the lines of:

```
   import {of, NEVER} from 'rxjs'
   import {map, catchError, shareReplay} from 'rxjs/operators'



   private inProg$ = {} // request cache
   getLookup(lookupName: string) {
     const stored = localStorage.get(lookupName) // check storage
     if (stored)
       return of(stored)
     const inProg = this.inProg$[lookupName] // check request cache
     if (inProg)
       return inProg
     let url = `..../getLooup?name= {lookupName}`;
     const req$ = this.httpClient.get(url).pipe( // build request
       map(data => {
         // Some other code to process the logic
         let processedData = someProcess(data);
         localStorage.set(lookupName, processedData); // populate storage
         delete this.inProg$[lookUpName]; // empty request cache
         return processedData
       }), 
       catchError(error => { // handle errors
         delete this.inProg$[lookUpName];
         // Log error and other code
         return NEVER // empty the cache and never emit
       }),
       shareReplay(1) // share it
     )
     this.inProg$[lookUpName] = req$ // populate request cache
     return req$
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

function getData(){
  let item = localStorage.getItem("data");
  if(item){
    console.log("--second----");
    subject.next(item);
  }else{
    //httpcall 
    console.log("--first");
    localStorage.setItem("data","TEST DATA");
  }
  return subject;
}

getData().subscribe(res =>{
  console.log("Success -- ", res);
},err=>{
  console.log("Error");
});

getData().subscribe(res =>{
  console.log("Success -- ", res);
},err=>{
  console.log("Error");
});
```

Comment: I understand your point of view but you keep data in two places `BehaviorSubject` and `localStorage`. I think when he keeps this data in `localStorage`, `BehaviorSubject` is unnecessary.

Comment: I Know this, but if you refresh the page you will not have any data in behaviorSubject.
To Store data in localstorage will keep the data even after reloading the page.

Comment: @KamilAugustyniak - As this function is returring observable, it need to change the code where it will first check either data is available or not. if it is available then it will return data from there otherwise need to call this function. To use the same function i beleive it is the right approach.